# How to sort a 2D array in Javascript using bubble sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

This is my function and need help making it work with a 2D array so when I pass

[ [39, 43, 32], [300, 44, 1] ]

It returns

[ [1, 32, 39], [43, 44, 300] ]

```
function bubbleSort(items) {
  var length = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) { 
      if(items[j] > items[j+1]) {
        var tmp = items[j];  
        items[j] = items[j+1]; 
        items[j+1] = tmp; 
        }
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Can you give examples of the output you are getting?

Comment: What logic is your desired output based on?  Your desired returned values aren't bubble sorted, you've completely changed the values of the arrays.  If it were simple bubble sorting the sub elements, you'd have `[[32,39,43],[1,44,300]]`

Answer (score 0):

For the exact example you've given the solution could be to just concatenate the two sub-arrays, sort the result and part the result into two sub-arrays.

```
function bubbleSort(items) {
  var length = items.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) { 
      if(items[j] > items[j+1]) {
        var tmp = items[j];  
        items[j] = items[j+1]; 
        items[j+1] = tmp; 
        }
     }
  }
  return items;
}

var a = [ [39, 43, 32], [300, 44, 1] ];
var a2 = bubbleSort(a[0].concat(a[1]));
a[0] = a2.slice(0,3);
a[1] = a2.slice(3,6);
```

This will get quite slow, if the array has many entries. It will also fail if the entries have different lengths. If they have different lengths you need the parse the array first and save the individual lengths in a second array to part the result correctly at the end. Concatenating and sorting would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to first "unnest" the nested array into a flat array, sort it, and copy the values back into the nested array:

```
function bubbleSortNested(items) {
  // create a flat copy of the nested items array
  var flat = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
    flat = flat.concat(items[i]);
  }
  // sort flat array
  for (var i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < (flat.length - i - 1); j++) { 
      if(flat[j] > flat[j+1]) {
        var tmp = flat[j];  
        flat[j] = flat[j+1]; 
        flat[j+1] = tmp; 
      }
    }
  }
  // copy sorted flat array back into original nested array  
  for (var i = items.length-1; i>=0; i--) { 
    items[i] = flat.slice(-items[i].length);
    flat.length -= items[i].length;
  }
  return items;
}

res = bubbleSortNested([ [39, 43, 32], [300, 44, 1] ]);
console.log(res);
```

Output:

> [ [1, 32, 39], [43, 44, 300] ]